# Android In-App onPurchaseStateChange

Tags: android, in-app

The sample code for the in-app feature has:

```
onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload)
```

and it brings information on the in-app purchase that was made (id, how much etc.).

I am missing the price that was paid in the transaction. How do I get it?

Comment: Can't you look it up by the item that was purchased?

Comment: Thing is - the app goes to the store, and when purchase done, I see only purchaseState, itemId, quantity, purchaseTime, developerPayload.

Comment: You have the itemId so you should be able to use the API to lookup how much that was. Just out of curiosity, why do you need to know the price? Shouldn't it just matter that they bought it?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you refer me to API example how to do it? I can use this for statistics, emails etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

afaik there is currently no way to query the price from an in app item.
you have to store the price offline in your app or on your own server.
this is especially annoying since the price can vary by region and/or currency.